# Where is my python tkinter grid from this inheritance?

Tags: python-3.x, model-view-controller, tkinter, grid, widget

this is a View and Controller part of a program that I am intending writing.  My question is why I can't see my grid.  My suspicion is that I am not inheriting correctly.

I think the problem is happening  here:

```
"self.frame=Small_Frame(self)"
```

This is what I understand from my code.  class Controller is inheriting from tk.  class View is inheriting from tk.Frame.  Up to here everything works.

class Small_Frame is my customer widget.  The grid is just 12 instances of class Small_Frame using grid() method.  I don't know why is it not showing up.  Please help me understand.  thank you.

```
import tkinter as tk

class View(tk.Frame):
    def  __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, bg= "yellow", bd =2, relief = tk.RIDGE)
        self.parent = parent
        self.controller = controller
        self.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)

        for r in range(3):
            self.rowconfigure(r, weight=1)
            for c in range(4):
                self.columnconfigure(c, weight=1)
                self.frame=Small_Frame(self)
                self.frame.grid(row = r, column = c, padx=1, pady = 1,  sticky=
                         (tk.N, tk.S, tk.W, tk.E))


class Small_Frame(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, borderwidth=1, relief="groove")
        self.parent = parent
        self.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)


class Controller():
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.view = View(self.root, self)
        self.root.title("notbook my own try")
        self.root.geometry("1200x650")
        self.root.config(bg="LightBlue4")
        self.root.mainloop()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    c = Controller()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are mixing `pack` and `grid` with widgets that share a common parent.

First, you're creating a `View` object as a child of the root window, and you're calling `pack` to add it to the root window.

Next, you are creating a series of `Small_Frame` instances, but you are neglecting to pass the parent to the `__init__` of the superclass so these instances become a child of the root window. The instance calls `pack` on itself, and then you call `grid` on the instance. Calling `grid` on the instance causes tkinter to get into an infinite loop as both `grid` and `pack` try to resize the parent in different ways. Each one triggers a redraw by the other one.

There are two things you need to do. First, remove `self.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)` from the `__init__` of `Small_Frame`. It's a bad practice to have a class call `pack` or `grid` on itself. The code that creates a widget should be responsible for adding it to the screen.

Second, you need to pass `parent` to `__init__` method of the superclass in `Small_Frame` so that `Small_Frame` is a child of the correct parent. Your `__init__` thus should look like this:

```
class Small_Frame(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, borderwidth=1, relief="groove")
        self.parent = parent
```

Comment: thank you for taking the time to answer.  I was confused on the grid and pack methods.  I did try with pack() on the view class, and it worked and I didn't know why it was clashing when I put the grid method.  This is my third app that I am writing as a practice.  I am confused sometimes.  thanks again.